# exclude folder from delete in Azure Web APP deploy task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

i've two applications (frontend and backend) in same Azure Web APP (Windows Plan).

The backend application is under `wwwroot\back` folder

The frontend application is under `wwwroot` folder

When i deploy the frontend using azure web app deploy task under Azure DevOps, the backend folder will be overwritting. Also , the same thing when deploy backend

Any idea , to do a exclude of same folder before deploy the front ?

Comment: The best and easiest way is to put both the back directory and the wwwroot directory in the site directory.

Comment: In this way, the time spent locating error messages or modifying scripts will be greatly reduced. When the program is updated in the future, it will not appear, because of forgotten or lack of steps, which program does not work on the front end or the back end.

Comment: Please remember that in path mappings, modify the file directory of virtual applications and add folders in the scm website.

Comment: Hello Sir @KevinLu-MSFT , 
I have been operated, I will test as soon as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea , to do a exclude of same folder before deploy the front ?

In Azure Web APP deploy task,  there is no such option could meet your requirements.

You could try to use  [Azure App Service deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops).

In Azure App Service deploy task, you could enable the `Select deployment method` option and input the `-skip` argument

[image]

For example:

```
-skip:Directory=\\back
```

OR

```
-skip:skipAction=Delete,objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=wwwroot\\back

-skip:skipAction=Update,objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=wwwroot\\back
```

Then the target folder will skip the option to modify the content.

For more detailed information, you could refer to this ticket:[Azure Pipelines: Exclude folders using Azure App Service Deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60537030/azure-pipelines-exclude-folders-using-azure-app-service-deploy) and this blog: [Demystifying MSDeploy skip rules](https://blog.richardszalay.com/2012/12/17/demystifying-msdeploy-skip-rules/).