# How to exclude artifact files after web deployment?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a build/release pipeline that is finally working correctly, but the developer asked that we exclude the stage config files (Web.Dev.config, Web.Test.config, Web.Prod.config) as well as the artifact archive itself from the site/wwwroot.

As you can see, every time we deployed, these zip files have been getting stored in the site root as well. They aren't harmful but it doesn't look good:

[image: wwwroot]

This is the Release App Service Web Deploy YAML:

```
steps:
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: project-123'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Azure Dev Service Connection'
    WebAppName: 'project-123'
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Project123 Dev Build Artifact/Release'
    enableCustomDeployment: true
    enableXmlTransform: true
```

How do we exclude those files after successful deployment?

Kudu dir structure:

[image: kudu dir]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on @theWinterCoder answer, Unfortunately, there doesn’t appear to be a way to honor the `MSDeploySkipRules` defined in the `csproj` file. Instead, files and folders can be skipped by defining the `AdditionalArguments` parameter of the Azure App Service Deploy (`AzureRmWebAppDeployment`) task.

Since there doesn’t appear to be any official documentation for the `-skip` rules, and the `MSDeploy.exe` [documentation that Azure Pipelines references is out-of-date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd569089(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), in 2012, ***richard-szalay*** wrote a useful article, “[Demystifying MSDeploy skip rules](https://blog.richardszalay.com/2012/12/17/demystifying-msdeploy-skip-rules/)”, which provides a lot of details for anyone requiring additional control.

***Brief Explanation:***

The `dirPath` argument represents the [Web Deploy Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd569040(v=ws.10)) to skip a directory whilst the `filePath` argument is used to skip an individual file.
The `dirPath` starts at `wwwroot`.
For ***ASP.NET Core*** applications, ***there’s another `wwwroot` under `wwwroot`***; as such, the `absolutePath` in that case would look like this: `absolutePath=wwwroot\\somefoldername` which would map to `D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\somefoldername`

***Solution:***

Therefore, since I’m skipping files, i set the web deploy provider to `filePath`, and since we’re ***not using .NET Core***, we set `absolutePath` to `Web.Dev.config`. That would map to `D:\home\site\wwwroot\Web.Dev.config`.
The same thing applies for the zip artifact, however, if we don’t prepend `\\` before the wildcard it will fail with following error:

```
Error: Error: The regular expression '.zip’ is invalid. Error: parsing ".zip" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing. Error count: 1.

-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=Web.Dev.config 
-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=Web.Prod.config 
-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=Web.Test.config 
-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=\\*.zip
```

or with regular expression:

```
-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath="Web.Dev.config|Web.Prod.config|Web.Test.config|\\*.zip"
```

Thats it

[image: Dir]

Answer (score 1):

You can add an additional arguments line to the yml that will tell it to skip certain files. It will look something like this:

```
AdditionalArguments: '-skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=wwwroot\\Uploads'
```

More details can be found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60537030/azure-pipelines-exclude-folders-using-azure-app-service-deploy)

Comment: Interesting, so does this skip them from deployment completely? or does it do its thing first to transform and web deploys from the zip file and then skips/excludes them from destination wwwroot?

Comment: Also we we'rent using `MsDeploySkipRules` in csproj so idk the argument equivalent in our case. Like what am i supposed to put instead of `dirPath` in the objectName and absolutePath? Is `dirPath` and `wwwroot\\Uploads` native arguments or custom args?

Comment: Truthfully I've never used this and just found this thread which should hopefully put you on your way to finding a solution :) I'm assuming you can alter the dirpath and wwwroot\\Uploads to reference your directory. So in your case wwwroot\\uploads would be the files you wish to omit, e.g. 379.zip (and have one for skip for each file). Annoyingly the documentation on it seems to be nonexistent which is a real shame