# How to make files not get overwritten during app service deployment task?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have Android/Apple pngs in the root as seen in the screenshot. Those icons are required in the root folder as some 404 requests were happening on mobile devices and including the icons in the root solves the issue. They are not committed to source control, which is why we don’t want the release pipeline to delete them when deploying a new build artifact.

The reason why they're not committed to source control is because they’re not actually used by the code, but sometimes there are requests for them from mobile devices, and those would throw 404 errors which would blow up the alerts channel. So they are just copied to the root for now to stop those 404 alerts.

[image: image.png]

During Release pipeline App Service Deployment, we need to make sure those files don't get overwritten. Here’s the current App Service Deployment YAML:

```
steps:

task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
displayName: ‘Azure App Service Deploy: edge-dev’
inputs:
azureSubscription: ‘Azure Dev Service Connection’
WebAppName: ‘edge-dev’
packageForLinux: ‘$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Build Artifact/Release’
enableCustomDeployment: true
AdditionalArguments: ‘-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=“Web.Dev.config|Web.Test.config|Web.Beta.config|Web.Prod.config|\*.zip” -retryAttempts:6 -retryInterval:10000’
enableXmlTransform: true
```

Is there some sort of option we can add so that the Android/Apple png files don't get overwritten? Currently every time a new build triggers the release deployment, the icons are removed and the developer has to keep uploading them manually after a deployment to ensure 404 errors don't occur.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT would you be able to help me out with this post too?

Comment: Using `-skip` in the AdditionalArguments option not work for you? Just like what have you did for the web.config in your previous thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68228310/how-to-exclude-artifact-files-after-web-deployment

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I thought that's used to skip build artifact files, not files already deployed under wwwroot.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I was looking into web deploy rules (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-r2-and-2008/dd568992(v=ws.10)) and found the `-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule` to be quite interesting given the context, i just am not sure how to apply it as an additional argument to skip the android/apple icon files:
In a sync operation, blocks deletions of files on the destination computer that do not exist on the source computer. This rule applies to the contentPath, dirPath, and filePath providers. This rule is disabled by default.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT `-skip` works, so i posted answer for that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to prevent icon overwriting:

theres actually 2 ways:

1. we could pass `-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule` in Azure App Service
   Deploy Additional arguments. The `DoNotDeleteRule` rule blocks
   deletions of files on the destination computer that do not exist on
   the source computer. This rule applies to the contentPath, dirPath,
   and filePath providers.
2. we could utilize the
   `-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=android-icon-144x144.png|android-icon-72x72.png|etc.`
   in the Azure App Service Deploy Additional Argument. It also blocks
   deletions of files on the destination computer, and we already are
   using the argument today actually for some files like the web.config

   ```
   -skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath="Web.Dev.config|Web.Test.config|Web.Beta.config|Web.Prod.config|android-icon-144x144.png|android-icon-192x192.png|android-icon-36x36.png|android-icon-48x48.png|android-icon-72x72.png|android-icon-96x96.png|apple-touch-icon-114x114.png|apple-touch-icon-120x120.png|apple-touch-icon-144x144.png|apple-touch-icon-152x152.png|apple-touch-icon-180x180.png|apple-touch-icon-57x57.png|apple-touch-icon-60x60.png|apple-touch-icon-72x72.png|apple-touch-icon-76x76.png|apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png|apple-touch-icon.png|favicon-16x16.png|favicon-32x32.png|favicon-96x96.png|apple-icon.png|ms-icon-144x144.png|ms-icon-150x150.png|ms-icon-310x310.png|ms-icon-70x70.png|\\*.zip"
   ```

   -retryAttempts:6 -retryInterval:10000